# Apply function to all columns in pd dataframe using variables in other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series of dataframes, some hold static values some are time series.

I have been able to add

I want to transpose the values from one time series to a new time series, applying a function which draws values from both the original time series dataframe and the dataframe which holds static values.

A snip of the time series and static dataframes are below.

```
Time series dataframe (Irradiance)
Datetime             Date        Time    GHI  DIF  flagR   SE    SA  TEMP                                                          
2017-07-01 00:11:00  01.07.2017  00:11    0    0      0  -9.39 -179.97  11.1   
2017-07-01 00:26:00  01.07.2017  00:26    0    0      0  -9.33 -176.47  11.0   
2017-07-01 00:41:00  01.07.2017  00:41    0    0      0  -9.14 -172.98  10.9   
2017-07-01 00:56:00  01.07.2017  00:56    0    0      0  -8.83 -169.51  10.9   
2017-07-01 01:11:00  01.07.2017  01:11    0    0      0  -8.40 -166.04  11.0 

Static dataframe (Properties)
         Bearing (degrees)  Inclination (degrees)
Home ID                                          
151631                 244                     29
151632                 244                     29
151633                 184                     44
```

I have written a function which I want to use to populate a new dataframe using values from both of these.

```
def dif(DIF, Inclination, GHI):
    global Albedo
    return DIF * (1 + math.cos(math.radians(Inclination)) / 2) + (GHI * Albedo * (1 - math.cos(math.radians(Inclination)) / 2))
```

When I have tried to do the same, but within the same dataframe I have used the Numpy vectorize funcion, so I thought I would be able to iterate over each column of the the new dataframe using the following code.

```
for column in DIF:
    DIF[column] = np.vectorize(dif)(irradiance['DIF'], properties.iloc['Inclination (degrees)'][column], irradiance['GHI'])
```

Instead this throws the following error.

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [Inclination (degrees)] of <class 'str'>
```

I've checked the dtypes for the values of Inclination(degrees) but it is returned as Int64, not str so I'm not sure why this error is being generated.

I'm obviously missing something critical here. Are there alternative methods that would work better, or at all? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it looks like the issue is with `iloc` which takes positions try using `loc`

Comment: Thanks Chris, this has pointed me in the right direction. I changed the line in the for loop shown in the original question to the below and it has worked as intended. 
    `DIF[column] = np.vectorize(dif)(irradiance['DIF'], properties.loc[:, 'Inclination (degrees)'][column], irradiance['GHI'])`